# Set the variable to another variable in the for statement

Tags: command-line, batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to set the variable of of the for statement to another variable. When I'm doing this:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%p in (plugins.txt) do set pp = %%p
```

It works correct. But I want to do more, So I do it after the ( and now it doesn't work. Why is that and how can I solve it?

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%p in (plugins.txt) do (
set pp = %%p
echo %pp%
echo %pp%
echo %%p)
```

**EDIT: Added input and desired output**

content of plugins.txt
`http://subversion/svn/dotCMSPlugins/CustomLogin/trunk`

Desired output
`CustomLogin`

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove trailing spaces, as with your `delims=<space>` you do

Comment: jeb's answer addresses the main problem. But be careful of extra spaces when you assign variables. You probably want `set pp=%%p`. Your code `set pp = %%p` has extra spaces, so the variable name includes a trailing space and the value has a leading space.

Comment: @dbenham: Hmmm, is this not the same I said? :-)

Comment: @jeb: oops, indeed you did. I somehow missed that sentence the 1st time I read your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting works, but the expansion works in an other way as expected.

The percent expansion will be done in the moment of **parsing** the parenthesis block, not in the moment of execution of the single commands.  [How does cmd.exe parse scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/463115)

Btw. Using spaces in the set statement isn't a good idea, as it creates a variable with a space, in your case `set pp = %%p` creates a variable named `pp<space>` with a value of `<space><content of %%p`.

You can get the desired results by using delayed expansion.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%p in (plugins.txt) do (
  set "myVar=%%p"
  set "myVar=!myVar:subversion/svn/dotCMSPlugins/=!"
  set "myVar=!myVar:/trunk=!"
  echo !myVar!
)
```

Comment: Aah ok, I understand, but how can I do now something with the !var! ? This is what I want to do, but doesn't work..  set !myVar!=!myVar:http://subversion/svn/dotCMSPlugins/=!

Comment: I added it in my sample. Use only `myVar` as variable name in the set statement, not `!myVar!`. The syntax of set is `SET <variable name>=<content>` or `SET "<variable name>=<content>"`, the second form ensures not to append unwanted spaces at the end.

Comment: Still not works 100%, but we are getting close! :) What I want is that this following sentences split the String, So that I get as final answer: CustomLogin

subversion/svn/dotCMSPlugins/CustomLogin/trunk/
subversion/svn/dotCMSPlugins/=
/trunk/=

Comment: You should edit your question: Show us what line(s) do you get from plugins.txt, and what do you expect the output should be

Comment: Sorry, I thought when I had the variable I can do it by myself, but it isn't working for me at the moment! This is the string I put in the String: http://subversion/svn/Plugins/CustomLogin/trunk/ and this is what I want from the output: CustomLogin

Comment: Then you should try to remove the unwanted text by replacing _exactly_ the right strings. `subversion/svn/Pulgins/` and not `.../dotCMSPlugins/`

Comment: Hmm that is not the problem, I copied from the wrong file ;-) This is the link: http://subversion/svn/dotCMSPlugins/CustomLogin/trunk/ So it is the same!

Comment: I see the fault! First you had "myVar=!myVarmyVar:, just one myVar to much.. I copied it so there was the mistake! Thanks alot! :) Danke!

Answer (score 2):

If your input file contain this line:

```
subversion/svn/dotCMSPlugins/CustomLogin/trunk
```

and you want to get this result:

```
CustomLogin
```

then the easiest way is to separate the line in tokens by / character and take the 4th token this way:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=4 delims=/" %%p in (plugins.txt) do (
  set "myVar=%%p"
  echo !myVar!
)
```

If the purpose of the FOR is just to get this result, then the delayed expansion is not even necessary:

```
for /F "tokens=4 delims=/" %%p in (plugins.txt) do (
  set "myVar=%%p"
)
echo %myVar%
```

Comment: This is a very nice way that I want to use. Only one problem. I need both, the full URL and the 'fifth token'. So I thought this is the best way: for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%p in (plugins.txt) do (set "Var=%%p"
for /F "tokens=5 delims=/" %%c in (%%p) do (set "myVar=%%c") DO SOME ACTIONS ) But he can't find the fifth token in the second for.

Comment: @Gynnad: The %%p must be enclosed in quotes. Also, I suggest you to use "delims=" instead of "tokens=* delims= " to get the entire line: `for /F "delims=" %%p in (plugins.txt) do (set "Var=%%p" for /F "tokens=5 delims=/" %%c in ("%%p") do (set "myVar=%%c") DO SOME ACTIONS)`